# Con que funcion encuentro la posicion de una letra dentro de un string?

Tags: java, string

Quiero saber en que posicion se encuentra la letra "x" dentro de la variable "ecuacion"

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        /*
        Resolver una ecuacion de primer grado con 1 variable 
        ejemplo:
        2x-1=5x+8
        */
        Scanner into=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese una escuacion de primer grado: ");
        String ecuacion=into.next();
        int caracteres=ecuacion.length();
        int num=caracteres;
        System.out.println(num);
        String[] caracter=new String[num];
        int paso=0;
        int pasa=1;
        for(int a=0;a<=num;a++)
        {
            //separador de letras
            caracter[a]=ecuacion.substring(paso,pasa);
            System.out.println(caracter[a]);
            paso++;
            pasa++;
        }
    for(int b=0;b<=num;b++)
    {

    }

}
```

Comment: En tu ejemplo `2x-1=5x+8` la `x` está dos veces, ¿cuál es la que quieres encontrar? ¿La primera, la segunda, las dos?

Comment: es que se me olvido pero segun yo, habia una funcion que encontraba la letra, claro solo la primera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Con el uso de `indexOf` puedes lograr lo que necesitas.

Puedes hacerlo de la siguiente forma para encontrar solamente la primera ocurrencia o todas las ocurrencias en caso de que lo necesites más adelante:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String ecuacion = "3x+1=3-2(2-2x)";
        String letra = "x";

        // Primera ocurrencia
        System.out.println("Primera ocurrencia...\nPosición: " + ecuacion.indexOf(letra)); // Imprime: 1

        // Encontrar todas las ocurrencias
        System.out.println("\nTodas las ocurrencias...");
        for (int i = -1; (i = ecuacion.indexOf(letra, i + 1)) != -1; i++) {
            System.out.println("Posición: " + i);
        } // Imprime: 1 y 12
    }
```

Resultado:

```
Primera ocurrencia...
Posición: 1

Todas las ocurrencias...
Posición: 1
Posición: 12
```